# Is there way to copy files from local machine to Dataflow harness instance in python + apache beam

Tags: python-3.x, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I want to validate data of each element in a ParDo function against the json schema file.

To make this work, I need to copy json schema file from my local machine to harness Dataflow instance created by Python Beam Dataflow SDK.

Each individual element represents data for separate table (variety of such different element is 26 meaning element can be dumped into any of these 26 tables based on the key field in the element representing the table name).

I want this json schema file to be copied only once at the start of Dataflow job on harness instance and then do validation of a element with already stored json schema.

I came across a post saying use DoFn.setup() method but not sure how to use it to copy file from local to harness machine.

Python 3.6, apache-beam 2.26.0

Any help and/or pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own SDK worker harness container image which contains your schema file, you can read more here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/environments/

For your use case, have you considered storing your schema file with Google Cloud Storage? You should be able to read the file with file io in your pipeline and feed the schema into your DoFn as side input.

Comment: Please accept this answer @Amol, it's the correct one